# 3 variable measurements of a box question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A box is to be constructed with a total volume of 600 $cm^3$, but the sides have different costs. The top, bottom, left and right sides cost 5 dollars per $cm^2$, but the front and back cost 3 dollars per $cm^2 .

What are the dimensions of the box that have the correct volume, but minimize cost?

I know that this is an xyz question since the dimensions of a box means 3 dimension (height, width, & length). But I'm not sure how to go about answering this question to  find the separate costs. (x, y, z)

Comment: You should have tried to propose at least the beginning of an expression  beyond 'it is a "xyz" problem". @Rafa Budria is a nice person who has served you the solution on a silver tray, but I am not sure you will do progresses without working by yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Yu have to minimize $c(x,y,z)=5(2xy+2yz)+3·2xz$ with the constraint $xyz=600$. $z$ in the constraint is easy to isolate: $z=\dfrac{600}{xy}$ Substituting you can reduce the problem to one with two variables,

$$c(x,y)=5(xy+\frac{2y600}{xy})+\frac{3·2x600}{xy}=$$

$$=5xy+\frac{6000}{x}+\frac{3600}{y}$$

Computing the partial derivatives and setting them to zero to find the stationary points:

$\dfrac{\partial c}{\partial x}=5x-\dfrac{6000}{x^2}=0$

$\dfrac{\partial c}{\partial y}=5y-\dfrac{3600}{y^2}=0$

$5x^3-6000=0\;;x=2\sqrt[3]{150}$

$5y^3-3600=0\;;y=2\sqrt[3]{90}$

With $z=5\sqrt[3]{2}$

No other stationary point.